# how to remove sub string from string without using any functions

Tags: python

I have text

> abcdblobefgblobhijk

How to remove the substring *blob* from the string without using any in built functions which provide 1 line solution like String.replace etc. In other words program should get the string as input and without using any inbuilt function should output the string without substring "blob".

Comment: Please include what you have tried.

Comment: Will regex work for you ?

Comment: How restrictive is *without using any functions*?

Comment: that depends on what you consider functions... everything in python is translated into functions when you look deep enough ... even accessing the characters in a string uses a function it fundamentally cant be done

Comment: If you don't want to use a function to remove `blob`, consider to do it like that : `var = "abcdefghijk"` :)

Comment: Fixed the question. I meant shortcut functions which provides 1 line solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to do it as "manually" as possible, without any shortcuts or python tricks,

I hope this helps in any way:

```py
text = "abcdblobefgblobhijk"
sub = "blob"

new_text =''
i=0
last_i = 0
while i <  len(text):
    if text[i:i+len(sub)] == sub:
        new_text += text[last_i:i]
        last_i=i+len(sub)
        i=i+len(sub)
    else:
        i+=1
new_text += text[last_i:i]

print(new_text)
```

Comment: just to mention, this of course uses string comparison, slicing, and concatenation. all of which actually are string functions... but I guess you were forbidding stuff like `replace`.

Comment: you can also not use len (by finding it with a loop) and not use slices(create the sub string yourself with a loop)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def remove(string, substr):
    str_length = len(string)
    substr_length = len(substr)

    for i in range(str_length):
        if string[i] == substr[0]:
            end = i + substr_length
            temp = string[i:end]

            if substr == temp: 
                return string[:i] + string[end:]

    return string
print(remove("Dhaval Dhanesha","sha"))
```

Output : Dhaval Dhane